Da fare altro che o altro da fare che?
"Non hai da fare altro che provare" o è meglio "non hai altro da fare che provare"?
"Non ho da dire nient'altro che grazie" oppure "non ho nient'altro da dire che grazie"?
Vanno bene entrambe le costruzioni? Se sì, quale sarebbe la differenza tra le due, a parte l'ordine diverso?
Grazie mille 

Nel primo caso entrambe le espressioni sono sintatticamente corrette, ma l'espressione che si usa correntemente e':

non ti rimane altro da fare che provare

che e' decisamente piu' vicina alla seconda.
Nel secondo caso l'espressione corretta sarebbe:

non posso dire altro che grazie

in questo caso l'espressione piu' vicina e' la prima
